# which is better android or j2me for image processing on phone

Tags: android, java-me, mobile-application

hey iam going to do some applications on mobile

using image processing applications

i was asking which will be suitable for me

as i will need a programming language that supports phonve devices with high

memory , 
what is the maxiumm number of ram size that has been released to work on phone

is there any name about the phone that support high memory so i can buy it to help me in my work

Comment: I believe android apps are limited to 16Mb of RAM but I'm not certain.

Answer (score 0):

Android and J2ME are two entirely different environments, and you don't really get to choose one or the other, the choice is dictated by the target handset.  If you're looking to do sophisticated image processing, you're going to find that the phones that are using J2ME as their application environment are completely unsuitable, as it's used on feature phones, not smartphones.